# how can I get a linked HashMap

Tags: java

I has a `Args` class,this class extend `HashMap` and has some methods:

```
public class Args extends HashMap{
    public myMethod_1(){
        //...
    }
    public myMethod_2(){
        //...
    }
    public myMethod_3(){
        //...
    }
}
```

now,I want to get a Linked `Args` instance,but exnted `LinkedHashMap`,

I can't change Args exnteds to `LinkedHashMap`,also can't change `Args` to a interfaces

can I get a linked `Args` instance ?

if not,how the best way to get a `LinkedArgs`? (not repeat `myMethod_1-3`)

Comment: Why can't you change Args to extend LinkedHashMap? Do you realize that LinkedHashMap extends HashMap? So by changing Args to extends LinkedHashMap, you're not giving up any functionality provided by HashMap.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're going for?  I don't understand why you cannot extend LinkedHashMap instead of just HashMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is change `Args` to extend `LinkedHashMap`.  (I know you said you can't ...)

If that is not an option, then the next best solution is to change `Args` to implement `Map` and delegate all of the methods in the `Map` API (and others as required) to a private `LinkedHashMap` instance.

If that is not an option, you could do the same with extends `HashMap`.  Basically, you *override* all of the methods in the parent `HashMap`, and delegate the actions to a private `LinkedHashMap` instance.  (It is UGLY but it works ... modulo that each `Args` object has a bunch of attributes that are initialized and never used.)